# Xcode error while archiving - There was an error parsing the Info.plist for the bundle at URL <0x6000010c6760>: NSCocoaErrorDomain - 3840

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I am setting up CI/CD using Github actions and Fastlane to archive and upload iOS App.

I keep getting this error only when building on Github actions cloud, archiving through Xcode, and running lane locally works normally.

I am using Xcode 13.2.1 and Macos 12

> XCBBuildService[83769:123294] There was an error parsing the
> Info.plist for the bundle at URL <0x6000010c6760>: NSCocoaErrorDomain 3840
>
> error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct
> format. (in target 'myiosapp-dev' from project 'myiosapp')

I tried moving Info.plist file to Resources folder, I validated it using plutil, added compileBitcode=false but nothing worked.

Here is my Info-dev.plist

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyIosApp (DEV)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>MYIOP</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1281780622334199</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.business</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>bank-app</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Camera is used to take pictures</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Location usage for maps SDK</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Microphone is used to take video</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Photo library is used to save photo to gallery</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Inter-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-ExtraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Inter-Thin.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: did you end up figuring out this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Go Runner -> Flutter -> AppFrameworkInfo.plist

And change the minimum sdk version to the minimum required and also on xcode minimum sdk version

It worked for me :)